# any other logic to convert from byte to String

Tags: java, string, byte, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a byte value to string. Please find the below example:

```
byte b = 'D';

String result = Byte.toString(b);
```

The output in this case is "68". But I want the output to be "D"[string]. is there any API method that does this conversion..? As toString is converting to the ascii value of D in this case(68).

Comment: Why are you taking byte instead you can use char right..???

Comment: `String result = new String(new byte[] { b }, Charset.forName("ASCII"));`

Answer (score 3):

The [`Byte.toString` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toString-byte-) takes the `byte` value as a number and converts it to a `String`, not the `char` value, so that is why you get `"68"`.

Cast it to a `char`, which the [`String.valueOf` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-char-) can use to create a `String`.

```
String result = String.valueOf((char) b);
```

Other methods:

```
String result = new String(new byte[] {b});
String result = new String(new char[] {(char) b});
String result = new Character((char) b).toString();
String result = Character.toString((char) b);
String result = new StringBuilder().append((char) b).toString();
String result = "" + (char) b;
```

Most solutions generally involving casting it to a `char` (which is a better type for `'D'` than `byte`) then creating a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
byte b = 'D';
String result = Character.toString((char) b);
```